# Transforming logical circuit in NANDs and ORs

Tags: nand

I can't transform this circuit in an exclusively NOR and another NAND circuit.
Everytime I tryed to simulate both circuits, neither of them gave me the correct result.

[image]

F=(notB)+AC

[image]

English is not my native language and I couldn't put it in better words, sorry.

Thank you.

Comment: The bolean F equation does not depicts the actual logic diagtam above, it is just an internal signal. The whole equation is :

> F= B'+ AC + (B+C)'

Comment: That's the simplified equation, sorry I didn't specify.

Comment: This is not a good question. You're not stating what you have tried nor how it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should show some work in your question. You don't, except that you do know that you optimized the gate diagram's resulting boolean expression. I suppose that's good enough for now. In any case, others may benefit. So I'll use your question as a foil of sorts.

If you have NANDs, then you want equations of the form: \$\overline{A \cdot B}\$. If you have NORs, then you want equations of the form: \$\overline{A + B}\$. It's not complicated.

You've already worked out the simplified form: \$\overline{B}+A\: C\$. But you need a large bar over all that which covers everything. So to start out you just double-bar everything.

$$\begin{align*}
F &= \overline{B}+A\: C\\\\
&=\overline{\overline{\overline{B}+A\: C}}\\\\
&=\overline{B\cdot \overline{A\: C}}
\end{align*}$$

That is already in perfect form for NANDs, as you should be able to see:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9xCcxm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's just how easy it is.

Now, can you do the same for NOR? You could follow the above recipe. Or you could just *cheat* and replace the NANDs with equivalent NORs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzQIWam.png)</sup>

So that you get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpp8XB.png)</sup>

That one can be optimized a little by replacing two consecutive inverters with a wire:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmB1B2.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since yesterday I managed to deduce the expression from both the diagram and the truth table (which I wasn't able to before).

Today I had the class and the teacher said it is correct with just the AND and OR gates.

I didn't had my work because the camera on my phone can't focus on what's written in the paper in graphite (Huawei ascend g610), sorry if it showed that I put in no work as I did and actually tried to put it here but couldn't.

Once again thank you.

Comment: @André Glad to hear it helped. If you are satisfied this is an answer, you can check it off as one. I think you get points for that, as well. If you still want other answers, then don't check it off.